# Android BindingConversion not working in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I try to implement a `BindingConversion` in Kotlin but I don't get it to work.

Tried the same where the `BindingConversion` is in a Java class and it seems to work. Maybe I just misunderstood the way it works, since I'm fairly new to Kotlin.

I basically stripped out everything which is not important to my problem.

The part in the .xml file.

```xml
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/the_item"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:text="@{ch.labrat.anima.utilities.Conv.valueFromPosition(item.gender)}"
/>
```

Kotlin version.

```
object Conv {
    fun valueFromPosition(position:Int):String {
        return "Test"
    }

}
```

Java version.

```java
public class Conv {

    @BindingConversion
    public static String valueFromPosition(Integer position){
        return "Test";
    }

}
```

While trying to add `@BindingConversion` to the method in the Kotlin version, I get an error of not using a static method.
Well. I just don't get it. Maybe someone can enlighten me?

Comment: Put `@JvmStatic` to your method signature.

Comment: Unbelievable! While pulling my hair out and devastating code for hours, this is probably the only variation I havent tried out. I always thought, an object in kotlin is somewhat like static, am I wrong? Furthermore. Is @JvmStatic something similar like companion object? 
Of course if you put your comment as answer I'll be happy to accept it, since it solves perfectly my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, when you create **object declaration** in Kotlin and put **some fields/methods** in that object, it acts like static *(when accessing in Kotlin)* code but **it's not static**.

It means that you can access that directly using that object declaration name (Same thing goes for **companion object**).

Hence, when doing data-binding *generated classes* are in Java format and now it tries to access your declaration of object from xml, but it can't because there's no static qualifier to it.

So, Annotating using **`@JvmStatic`** marks method/field to be complied by **JVM** as static. hence, now Java code interpret it as static while accessing it from Kotlin code.

Read more from **[here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods)**.

Comment: Now that makes totally sense. Thank you very much for the indepth explanation.

Comment: Happy to help :)